# Calling ajax function onload and onclick simultaneously

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a Ajax function in a external javascript file which is:

ajax.js

```
function webservice(x){

   jQuery.ajax
            ({
                //some code here
            });

  Data = function(data){
                    if(x==1)
                            {
                                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                                {
                                     webservice(i);
                                alert"Onload");
                                }
                            }
                            else 
                            if(x==5)
                            {
                                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                                {
                                webservice(i);
                                alert ("Onclick");
                                }
                            }

        }
```

I have another html page which is:

webservice.html

```
 <html>
 <title>Call web service</title>
 <head>
 <script type="text/Javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type = "text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
 <script>

 window.onload=function()
 {
   webservice(1)('onload');    //call 1 

 }

 </script>
 </head>

  <body>


  <input id="webservice"  type = "button" name = "webservice" value = "Call Webservice"       
  onclick="webservice(5)"/>


  </body>
  </html>
```

So I want to call the same function in onLoad and onclick of button so that both the calls will run simultaneously.
But when onload runs for e.g say 3 times and I click button then onload stops and onclick runs.
I want onclick also to run and onload to start from 4th iteration and both should display alert simultaneously or 1 by 1.
So please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Any alternative methods are also welcome.

Comment: Use jQuery's event handlers (e.g., `$.on()`) instead of inline or `window.onload`. Especially `window.onload`, jQuery can remove your event for its own. If you're using jQuery, best just to use jQuery's handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$.ajax` is an asynchronous function. In your current version, your code is called potentially before the end of the AJAX call. Therefore, you have a wird behavior.

To fix that, your code must be moved into the success callback like this :

```
function webservice(x) {
    var inputParam = x;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            if (inputParam  == 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    webservice(i);
                    alert("Onload");
                }
            } else if (inputParam  == 5) {
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    webservice(i);
                    alert("Onclick");
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('an error occurred!');
        }
    });
}
```

**Furthermore, avoid inline JS.**

Replace

```
window.onload=function()
 {
   webservice(1)('onload');    //call 1 
 }
```

By

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    webservice(1);//call 1 
});
```

And

```
  <input id="webservice"  type = "button" name = "webservice" value = "Call Webservice"       
  onclick="webservice(5)"/>
```

By

```
$('#webservice').click(function(){
    webservice(5);
});
```

Comment: Thank you sdespont for your efforts. But when I run according to your changes by including Data in success function it is saying Data not defined whereas if I run it outside like I told it is running.

Comment: Still not working. I need to call Data as it is defined in the url of jQuery.ajax. So cannot avoid it.

Comment: If there are any alternative methods then those too are welcome.